# Four counted as dead & Agunot

Tags: talmud-gemara, marriage, women, divorce, aguna

Nedarim 64b relates of the Gemara: "it was taught in a baraita: Four are considered as if they were dead: A pauper, and a leper, and a blind person, and one who has no children."

Could one make an argument for a woman who wants out of her marriage that if her husband has become any of those four, it is as if he had died and therefore she is not an aguna?

Or, since a woman is entitled to a divorce if her husband cannot maintain her (i:e; a pauper, plus  Ketubot 48a:1-13 states that "she ascends with him to his social status and does not descend with him") or give her children, then do we say that the middle two likewise automatically entitle her to divorce (since a leper might be repulsive to his wife and a blind man might also not be able to maintain her)?

Comment: Being entitled to a divorce implies she's still married.

Comment: Hence the 'Or' bit at the beginning of that section. 
As in 'or, if he isn't counted as dead, but rather she is still married, then...' etc

Comment: See the Mishnah and Tosefta of Kesubos 7:10

Comment: Thankyou. That explains for the leprosy, but I'm not seeing the blindness discussed?

Comment: @ANH that’s in the Tosefta

Comment: Ah, thankyou again!

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: It's very clever but I think it's "too clever by half." Clearly those people are not actually dead. Would you argue that killing a poor person isn't murder (since he's already dead)? Can a childless person count for a minyan? There are many other gemaras that say someone who X is "not really alive" or that X is like murder. See Pesachim 113a. Those are not legal realities.

Comment: Yeah I realised it was unlikely, but since it was showing up in a lot of the interpolated parshah readings that I was doing (for example, in reference to Jacob, Dathan and Aviram, Pharaoh) I was simply curious if it had ever been used as an argument, given how difficult some aguna situations become when a husband is recalcitrant about divorce, especially if the situation causes him embarrassment - Hence why I also wanted to check if they counted for divorce at any rate.